# Create new user on strongloop without inputting email

Tags: node.js, authentication, loopbackjs, strongloop

Our login model only require user to enter a username and password, email being optional, however loopback User model requires an email before we can create a new user.

Is there a way to create a new user in Strongloop without having to input the email?

Comment: Look this  https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1137

Answer (score 4):

> At the moment, it is not possible to allow non-unique user emails. One
>   of the reasons is that User.login supports both email and username,
>   i.e. you can login by entering an email and a password.

Pleas see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26860145/3545790).

But don't worry,there is an ugly (or maybe creatively) way to resolve this issue:

1.extend from User model in `common/models/base-user.json`:

```
{
  "name": "baseUser",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "hidden":["email"],
  "properties": {
    "username": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "index": {
        "unique": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2.create random email for each user before sign up in `common/models/base-user.js`:

```
module.exports = function (BaseUser) {
  BaseUser.beforeRemote('create', function (context, user, next) {
    var req = context.req;
    req.body.email =Date.now()+"a@b.cc";
    next();
  });
};
```

3.define baseUser model and hide User model in `server/config-model.json`

```
"baseUser": {
    "dataSource": "MongoDB",
    "public": true
},
"User": {
   "dataSource": "MongoDB",
   "public": false
}
```

Comment: For me, that can only be called creative :). OP stated that email was optional tough, so it's only missing an extra field for those who actually provide their email adress

Comment: [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133117/3931488) for an update

Answer (score 0):

There currently is not a way to alter the required properties of a built-in model, according to the docs:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Customizing+models

Answer (score 0):

[@viam had the right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36372428/3931488), but that answer's code is deprecated with the latest Loopback (^3.17 or ^4) today due to API changes over time.

[Specifically deprecated](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Model-hooks.html): `BaseUser.beforeRemote('create',...`

Here's and updated base-user, assuming Loopback 3, based on a more full implementation found in [Ella API](https://github.com/Vandivier/ella-api/blob/master/server/models/EllaUser.js):

```
module.exports = function (Ellauser) {
    Ellauser.observe('before save', function filterProperties(ctx, next) {
        let oInstance = ctx.instance;

        if (oInstance) oInstance.email = oInstance.email || 'placeholder@example.com';

        next();
    });
};
```